# scanf и сканирование \n и пробелов

Tags: c

Всем привет
Есть необходимость пропустить 1 символ переноса строки

```
scanf("\n");
```

данным способом пропускаются и пробельные символы, идущие после \n 
Как можно пропустить лишь 1 символ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один перевод строки пропускается так:

```
scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

А вот последующие пробелы скорее всего съедаются следующими спецификаторами формата.