# Почему ввод происходит только со второй строки? С

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Мне нужно ввести в массив строк текст (M - количество строк в тексте)
Но столкнулся с проблемой, в том, что при i=0 всегда вместо запроса строки с клавиатуры записывается

> \n

, а при i>1 и т.д. уже происходит запрос и запись в массив.

. Почему так происходит и как исправить?

```
scanf("%d", &M);
for( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        input_printf("Input str # %d :", i + 1);
        fgets(text[i], 81, stdin);  
    }
```

Использовал fgets потому что gets не работает в 17 VS.

Comment: `при вводе запись в строке начинается с 1-й строки` - расшифруйте, что вы хотели сказать

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov исправил)

Comment: Что за функция `input_printf`?

Comment: @Qwertiy♦  из библиотеки для тестирования (когда включается тестирование этой проги, ответ в input_printf  не учитывается)

Comment: @DartWelder, а как она называется? И откуда взялась?

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ testing.h, у нас в унике так проверяют задания)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `scanf` оставляет перевод строки в буфере.

> А как это исправить?

Например так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/956613/178988

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Напримекр так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/956613/178988

Comment: @AK, да, именно так)) Надо вообще дубликат найти - у нас же сто раз такие вопросы были и там с кучей вариантов как от символа избавиться.